# Restrict iCloud contact/calendar sync

Tags: iphone, ios, synchronization, contacts, icloud

I am working on an application in which we have provided option for remote contact, calendar, etc wiping. The functionality is working fine until we had discovered about iCloud.

Now when we send wipe command from web to device, it deletes all the contacts from the device as expected. But, if user has iCloud account set and is ON for contacts, when contacts are deleted because of our application's wipe command, contact application will inform iCloud about it which in term will delete all the contacts of user from iCloud.

When user sends wipe and he might have initially had setup iCloud account, he may not be aware about this side effect.

Is there any workaround we can restrict the iCloud deleting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this make sense.  Deleting the contacts without deleting them from iCloud would not work because the device would simply download them again from iCloud.

Are you trying to create a type of MDM app?

Comment: hmm ... probably what you are saying is right. Even if I succeed from not deleting the contacts from cloud, as soon as device sync, it would download them back. I am developing anti-theft kind of app. So if the device is stolen, user can send remote wipe command which would delete all contacts from device. But with iCloud ON, it would defeat the whole purpose. Is there any way I can turn OFF iCloud when my app is running? This would probably do the trick :P

Comment: Apple already supports the ability to remotely wipe your device.

Comment: ha ha ... yes I know that. But I am getting paid to work on this app, so doesn't matter if apple has provided it :P right?